UseState only getting the last value
i'm learning reactJS and in this case i'm trying to assign passangers to a variable so i can later loop their name, ID..
I'm getting data from a formdata from a different file:
-Name
-Forename
-ID
I'm getting the data from "datos" variable so if in my for loop i'm getting datos.nombre in a correct way but cosole loging pasajero only logs the last person.
 const { state } = useLocation();
    const [datos] = useState(state);
    const [pasajero, setPasajero] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            setPasajero((prev) => ({
                ...prev,
                nombre: datos.nombres[i],
                apellido: datos.apellidos[i],
                DNI: datos.DNI[i],
            }));
        }

    },[]);

    console.log(pasajero)


in my for loop i tried to assign the passanger but i'm getting the last value when i want to get every person in that for loop

pasajero state likes a derived data, it should not be an state and you don't need an effect , see https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state

Why the useState of [datos] is the state from useLocation?

I'm using useLocation because i'm gathering the data i passed from another component:
navigate('/datos', { state: { nombres: nombres, apellidos: apellidos, DNI: DNI, length: nombres.length, precio: precio } }
`

I got it now! removed the useEffect and created an empty array and pushed data inside that empty array using the for loop i had, instead of using the useState :D
Sorry it's a little confusing

Changed it by creating an empty array and then pushing data while looping through my data using for loop.
It works for what i wanted it for (display passanger information) for the payment (which obviously doesn't exist in this project :D )
const { state } = useLocation();
const datos = state;
const pasajeros = [];

for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
    pasajeros.push({ nombre: datos.nombres[i], apellidos: datos.apellidos[i], DNI: datos.DNI[i] })
}
console.log(pasajeros)


import { useState } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const MyComponent = () => {
const { state } = useLocation();
const [datos] = useState(state);
const pasajeros = datos.map((_, index) => ({
nombre: datos.nombres[index],
apellidos: datos.apellidos[index],
DNI: datos.DNI[index],
}));
console.log(pasajeros);

return (
    <div>
        {/* Render your pasajeros data here */}
    </div>
);

}
export default MyComponent;
